How to calculate the confidence intervals for a time-lagged cross correlation?
I am trying how to calculate the confidence intervals for a time-lagged cross-correlation graph. It's a bit complicated for me to understand probability concepts. I have investigated the formulas to do this, and I have found this
1 (at the 5% level) are ±2/√n. n is (I suppose) is the data number.
[2]  \bar{x}-z_{\alpha/2} \frac{\sigma }{\sqrt{N}}
I don´t know what is the difference between them.
This is my graph:

